# Is there a short way of writing (x==a || x==b || x==c)?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, syntax

Something like x == (a|b|c) but that doesn't work.

Comment: In certain cases `MemberQ[{a,b,c}, x]`  could be used but it does pattern matching/SameQ  rather than EqualQ. Depends of your use case.

Answer (score 9):

```
AnyTrue[{a, b, c}, EqualTo[x]]
```

or

```
Or @@ Thread[x == {a, b, c}]
```

Comment: Those give ways to do it but they're longer! I was hoping for a concise syntax for "x equals any of these discrete values"

Comment: @JLo  `Element[x, {a, b, c}]`?

Comment: Works: `Simplify[x == 5, x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3]`
Doesn't work: `Simplify[x == 5, x \[Element] {1, 2, 3}]`

It knows the 1st one is false but not the 2nd.

Comment: @JLo `{1,2,3}` is not a valid domain for `Element`, so of course not...

Comment: Isn't that what you suggested? I'm confused. That's the same thing as `Element[x, {a, b, c}]` with values substituted.

Comment: @JLo - I did not suggest anything.

Comment: @ciao Sorry! I didn't realise you weren't @cvgmt! Yes, I agree with you that that would't work, I was just responding to them.

Comment: I would say that both of cvgmt's solutions to your problem are concise ways to write "x equals any of these discrete values", using some definition of "concise" which is tailored to programming in Mathematica. They both look short and clean to me. If you want something that uses less characters, I suggest you define ``f[x_, A__] := Or @@ Thread[x == {A}]`` and use ``f[x,a,b,c]``.

Answer (score 7):

You can make it work if you really want to! ;) (Though this would have to be re-evaluated every session—unless you put it in an init file or something.)

```
Unprotect[Or]

Or /: (x_ == HoldPattern[Or[ys__]]) := Thread[Unevaluated[x == Or[ys]], Or]

Protect[Or]

(* In:  *) x == (a || b || c)
(* Out: *) x == a || x == b || x == c
```

(Note that this uses `Or` (`||`), not `Alternatives` (`|`).)

Other possibilities (with a fresh `Or`):

```
(* Just use thread directly: *)

Thread[x == (a || b || c), Or]

(* Map the equality function: *)

x == # & /@ (a || b || c)

(* or equivalently: *)

EqualTo[x] /@ (a || b || c)

(* Define a new function: *)

OrEqual[x_][ys__] := Thread[x == Or[ys], Or]

OrEqual[x][a, b, c]

(* Use MemberQ, but this is pattern-based: *)

MemberQ[{a, b, c}, x]

MemberQ[x][{a, b, c}]
```